# Connecting ONOS web application with MariaDB . ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, onos

I am trying to make a custom web application on top of ONOS and I am having a difficulty to connect my application to the MariaDB server located on my localhost. What I've done is applying MariaDB dependencies to the POM.xml file of my application.I am using IntelliJ Idea Community version and I have less knowledge in developing Java web application.

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
       <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.0</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem but with SQLite.  Any luck with resolving it?

Comment: @reservoirman im sorry for not looking at this post for a long time. Basically there are two ways to achieve that. Either we want to use Maven or BUCK approach., we have to specify our dependencies inside app.xml and features.xml or we specify our dependencies inside ~/onos/lib/ and modify few other BUCK files. If you want a step by step instructions, you may email me at nilarimogard@outlook.com